# How can you add to a geom_bar based on a full-year calculation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you have annual data for a few years, but for the most recent year only part-year data, is there a programmatic way to extend the most recent year's bar, using ggplot2 and geom_bar presumably, to indicate what the full year would be if the part-year data were extrapolated?

Here is a tiny example.  Assume the 2014 figure is for half the year.  Is there a way to add "on top of the bar" the same amount, i.e., extrapolate the half-year data, and color or fill it differently?

```
yrs <- data.frame(Id = c(1, 2, 3), Year = c(2012, 2013, 2014), Amount = c(5e6, 6e6, 3e6))

ggplot(yrs, aes(x = Year, y = Amount)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a type variable to differentiate between actual and projected income, something like this?

```
yrs <- data.frame(Id = c(1, 2, 3,4), Year = c(2012, 2013, 2014,2014), 
Amount = c(5, 6, 3, 4))


yrs$type <- c(rep("Actual",3),"Projected")
```

You can then plot the bar chart with fill set to type like this:

```
ggplot(yrs, aes(x = Year, y = Amount,fill=type )) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Giving you this graph:

[image]

As far as extending the data, there are many ways to forecast in R. Perhaps the simplest is using a linear model: `lm`.

If you use your dataset without the most recent year, and run `lm(Amount ~ Year, data = years)` you will get output like:

```
 Call:
 lm(formula = Amount ~ Year, data = yrs)

 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)         Year
       -2007            1
```

You can use the coefficient on year to "extrapolate" a value for the newest year. So in this case our extrapolated value for 2014 would be 7.

```
yrs$Amount[2] + linear_model$coeff[2]
 Year
    7
```

Comment: @bjosoph, that is excellent!  Thank you.  Your lm suggestion is much, much fancier than I thought of.  My thought is to define the partial year as an object YTD, then create an object Project that multiplies YTD by number of months left in year/number of months elapsed.  On your numbers and a half year, YTD equals 4 times 6/6 or 4.  But then, how do I have ggplot recognize YTD for the fill type?

Comment: you can create a new column called `ytd` (or whatever) and give it two values `acutal` and `projected` and then just do `fill=ytd` or whatever you called the column